# PHP validating data against another table

Tags: php, sql-server

I am very new to PHP and I am having some issues with validating the data against what is already stored in another table. The idea is pretty simple in that someone will enter some data against a works order and write that to the database. The data will only be written to the database if the works order number exists in a separate table.

```
$sqlv = "Select count (worksorderv) from validationtest where worksorderv = ('".$_POST["worksorder"]."')";
$checkwo = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlv, array(), array('Scrollable' => 'buffered'));

 if (sqlsrv_fetch_array($checkwo) < 1) {
  echo "That is not a valid works order.<br />";
  }else{
$sql = "INSERT INTO main_table (worksorder, part, quantity, date)
      VALUES ('".$_POST["worksorder"]."','".$_POST["part"]."','".$_POST["quantity"]."',GETDATE())";
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

I have tried to create a count, so if the works order does not exist within the table it will output a 0 else it exists and can be committed to the database.

if I hardcode a single number in I can get it to work, but I can not get it working using the $_POST["worksorder"] which is the form entry.

it seems to ignore and writes all entries regardless of if the count is 0 or 1

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlsrv_fetch_array()` returns an array, and you are using this result in your comparison:

```
if (sqlsrv_fetch_array($checkwo) < 1) {
```

You probably want to check the actual column that holds the result of the count:

```
$sqlv = "Select count(worksorderv) as CNT from validationtest where worksorderv = ('".$_POST["worksorder"]."')";
// ...
$result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($checkwo);
if ($checkwo['CNT'] < 1) {
```